# Какой хороший компилятор для php -> exe?

Tags: php, компилятор

Привет Всем! Какой хороший компилятор для php под windows приложение. В гугл набрал "php compiler" но все бракованные =(. Есть ли более-менее?

Comment: А зачем?

Comment: Ну наверное кроме php человек ничего не знает, а писать десктоп приложения хочется.
Хотя с такой постановкой вопроса по моему и с php человек не знаком.

Comment: :)

Comment: Чего вы все накинулись?) Как видите, есть такой компилятор. С кнопочками, формами и прочим. Да, у готового приложения все предсказуемые минусы (скорость, память, вес экзешника), но, например, у меня был чисто спортивный интерес и я на этой штуке плеер делал) Для утилиток "чисто для себя" - вообще самое оно, понаделал 20 штук, кинул на флеху и в путь)

Comment: Зачем? Так как на си я незнаю как с дизайном работать, кроме цвета текста и заливки больше не знаю. php базовые знания есть+ html и css. И хотелось написать программу с php и html+css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinBinder](http://winbinder.org/download.php) Парам-пам-пам, он существует =)

Между прочим, хорошая, годная штуковина. В свое время очень пригодилась. Мануал в комплекте, при хорошем знании php - сутки-двое на освоение.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вас заинтересует [решение](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/) от Facebook.

Речь идет о интерпретации php кода в аналог на С++, после компиляция под что угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошего нет. Наиболее разумное - поставить денвер-портабл и запускать из-под него. Ну или выучить какой-нибудь компилируемый язык.

Что же касается т.н. компиляции - поищите NuSphere NuCoder. Он запускает под собственной системой PHP-Express. В общем, это тоже далековато

[Транслятор в C++](http://www.mibsoftware.com/php2cpp/)